# Make a single letter clickable C# windows form application

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I wonder, how to make a single letter clickable on a `RichTextBox` or `Label` (doesn't matter). Previously I used buttons on a text, but it looks ugly.
Is there any other way?

For example: letter `B` in word `TextBox` shoud be clickable

Some text in Text**B**ox.

Comment: http://dict.mosmetod.ru/single/10 I would like have something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add link controls to your RichTextBox like this:

```
richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, 16);
richTextBox1.Text = "Text";

var clickablePart = new LinkLabel();
clickablePart.Text = "B";
clickablePart.AutoSize = true;
clickablePart.Font = richTextBox1.Font;
clickablePart.LinkClicked += clickablePart_LinkClicked;
clickablePart.Location = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.TextLength);
richTextBox1.Controls.Add(clickablePart);
richTextBox1.AppendText("     ox");

private void clickablePart_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
}
```

Result:

[image]

You might need to play around the size to get it to fit exactly. But I think that would not be a problem for you.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks.